# Boolean flags handing in Drools conditions

Tags: drools

We are working on a monitoring application in which we follow the processing of a task in a set of applications.
We have a set of drools rules matching our needs but we have some performance issues (we may have easily up to 50k objects in session).
We are looking for best pactices

This question is about bloolean flag usage.
We are working to remove most of `org.drools.core.rule.constraint.MvelConstraint: Exception jitting: ...` warns.

We have often such warn on boolean flags.

for example in:

```
rule "PropagateDeprecation"
when
    $parent:BaseChainStep( $parent.Deprecated )
    $child:BaseChainStep( $parent.Id == $child.Parent,  !$child.Deprecated )
then
    modify($child){
        setDeprecated(true)
    }
end
```

we have warn on both $parent.Deprecated and !$child.Deprecated.

We would like to understand why there is such warn on boolean flags.

We would like to know also the impacts of the warn on composed conditions.
For example in:

```
rule "App1_TriggerExpected"
when $chainStep:App1ChainStep(
         HasChain
         , HasParent
         , !$chainStep.Deprecated
         , Status in ("error", "closed")
         , Places != null
         , Analysis != null)
then
    ..
end
```

if we have the warn on the first condition `HasChain`, how is resolved the when clause ?
Does other conditions are evaluated too (with iteration on all App1ChainStep objects) or some "index" are still used to help ?

If its matter, we are using flags as boolean (and not Boolean) to ensure false value as default.

**Edit:**

The problem may be linked to extended classes. In our use case we have something like:

```
declare BaseChainStep
     parent : GUID
     deprecated : boolean
end

declare App1ChainStep extends BaseChainStep
     // specific App1 fields
end
```

BaseChainStep fields may be manipulated in rules using App1ChainStep objects or BaseChainStep objects.

```
 rule "deprecateApp1"
 when $app1:App1ChainStep( BusinessLogicCondition )
 then
      modify($app1) {
           setDeprecated(true)
      }
 end
```

Then the deprecated flag is propagated to App1 children using "PropagateDeprecation" rule.

Boolean flag causing warn are declared in BaseChainStep class.

Answer (score 0):

Although you are deviating from the conventional way of accessing attributes, this should not trigger the warning you have reported. I can't reproduce this using 6.3.0. You should add (a) the Drools version (b) the Java code for a class BaseChainStep with which the problem can be reproduced with the rule as shown.

This is another (much simpler) way of writing rules combining boolean attributes:

```
rule bool1
when
  X( big, fast )
then
  System.out.println( "big fast X" );
end
```

You may even use boolean operators:

```
rule bool2
when
  X( big && ! fast )
then
  System.out.println( "big slow X" );
end
```

Note the simple use of field name, assuming conventional naming, e.g., `big` for the field, `isBig` and `setBig` for the accessors.

Comment: I just added an edit on my question. It may be linked to extended classes.

Comment: I have inserted objects according to your classes declared in DRL code, and rules along the ones I've stated in my answer work just fine. - Please don't post "maybes" - if it can't be reproduced it can't be diagnosed and it can't be cured.

Comment: Ok i will reproduce on a simple test case and repost. But i really have the warn on flags for rules using Base classes explicitly (i will confirm).

Comment: And the Drools version may be essential.